# Unity3D two box colliders(2D) common border problem

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As the image shows, two box colliders(2D) stay close together, while a circle collider(2D) fall on the common border.

I hope it will bounce forward (blue arrow), but sometimes it bounce back (green arrow).

I have checked the position and the width, and have make sure the box colliders(2D) are touch to each other perfectly.

(positions: (0,0), (2,0), widths: 2, 2)

I am new on Unity, and have no idea how to prevent the strange bounce.

Please give me some help, thanks.

Image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe It'll work if you edit the colliders like this:

[image: Picture]

I am not quite sure what is the problem, I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank for answering. I have already tried, but the strange bounce still happened.